# How to restrict editing of myapp's contacts?

Tags: android

I implemented contacts synchronization for my application. (SyncAdapter and so on)
It's working fine, but maybe someone know how I can restrict this contacts from being changed by user?

Thanks in advance,
 Dmitry.

Comment: like Skype or twitter contacts.

Comment: I guess you can create your own class for storing contacts which will be limited to your own application.
I hope this will help.
[link.](http://www.cnblogs.com/lycoris/archive/2011/05/13/2037716.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Manifest permissions and more specifically WRITE_CONTACTS and READ_CONTACTS. You can check more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but those permissions can only restrict reading/writing contacts for my app.
That's not what I wanted